# Java SimpleDateFormat ParseException for 12 hr format

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I am getting exception while trying to parse a date string to java.util.Date.

Here is what I am doing,

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";
String strDateTime = "2016-03-04 11:30 am";

SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            Date date = sdformat.parse(strDateTime);
            System.out.println(sdformat.format(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and got this

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-03-04 11:30 am"
    at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396)
    at testing.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:18)
```

I have done this so many times and pattern looks correct to. may be I am not seeing what I did wrong here
I am using Java 8 and my execution environment in eclipse is 8 too.
until today this code was working fine.

However if I change date string to **a.m.** =>  `"2016-03-04 11:30 a.m."`
it parses successfully
output:
`2016-03-04 11:30 a.m.`

This behavior is same wit LocalDateTime.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-03-04 11:30 am' could not be parsed at index 17
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2050)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:493)
    at testing.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:27)
```

All the examples of `SimpleDateFormat` I have seen on internet just uses "am/pm" and not "a.m./p.m."
What could I be doing wrong here.
-Thanks

Comment: Your code runs successfully for me, under Oracle JDK 15.0.1. Javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't show dots in 'am' and 'pm' either. Which is to say: I don't know! Which JDK/JVM are you using (i.e., Oracle, OpenJDK, IBM J9, ...)? And, what's your locale? I'm en_US.

Comment: I use oracle jdk

Comment: I would suspect a locale issue. Does it work if you explicitly specify the US locale?

`SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);`

Comment: if I use Locale then SimpleDateFormat works but LocalDateTime doesnt

Comment: Playing with `LocalDateTime`, it seems that the AM/PM markers are case-sensitive, and with `en_US` locale, it works with 'AM' but fails with 'am'.

Comment: FYI, both `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a locale issue - in the `en_US` locale your code works successfully. You can print out the AM/PM marker text associated with each locale using a loop like:

```java
for (Locale locale : SimpleDateFormat.getAvailableLocales()) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);
    String[] amPmStrings = sdformat.getDateFormatSymbols().getAmPmStrings();
    System.out.println("Locale " + locale + ": " + amPmStrings[0] + ", " + amPmStrings[1]);
}
```

This shows that, e.g., the `en_CA` locale uses the format you describe:

```
Locale en_CA: a.m., p.m.
```

If you want to use 'am' and 'pm' (or 'AM' and 'PM' - it appears to be case-insensitive), you can force the `en_US` locale when creating the formatter:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. my local environment doesnt throw error. only canadian web server